# Oracle SQL - Extract YYYYMM from YYYYMMDD, when column type is NUMBER(38)

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a column named `DATEOFORDER`, which type is `NUMBER(38)`.

When I run a SELECT query I get Year-Month-Day results such as:

> 20161230, 20160531 or 20170330

What I hope to achieve is to limit the number of characters displayed to Year-Month only. So I would get the following:

> 201612, 201605 or 201703

I tired using functions like TO_CHAR or EXTRACT but with no success.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can always divide by `100` to remove the last 2 digits.  So something like this could work:

```
select to_char(trunc(dateoforder / 100))
  from tbl
```

Answer (score 1):

**Oracle Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE your_table ( dateoforder ) AS
SELECT '20161230, 20160531 or 20170330' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20161230' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20160531' FROM DUAL UNION ALL
SELECT '20170330' FROM DUAL;
```

**Query**:

```
SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE( dateoforder, '(\d{6})\d{2}', '\1' ) AS monthoforder
FROM   your_table
```

**Output**:

```
MONTHOFORDER
------------------------
201612, 201605 or 201703
201612
201605
201703
```

Comment: Thank you for the swift reply. Unfortunately I get an error message: _ORA-00904: "REGEXP_REPLACE": invalid identifier_.

Comment: What was the query you ran? The one above works without errors when copied verbatim. This is the [Oracle documentation for `REGEXP_REPLACE`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions130.htm).

Comment: I am a beginner who has started working with SQL just recently. So  it's very possible I've done something wrong. However, great many thanks for replying to my post.

Comment: It is a number field, so string '20161230, 20160531 or 20170330' is not possible.

Answer (score 1):

```
select substr(to_char(dateoforder), 1, 6) from tbl
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use `substr(string, a,b)` operator that selects a substring from `string` with values between `a` and `b` as mathguy suggested.

To get the string you should use to_char on dateoforder.